# mapbasic learning - vbscript or visualbasic knowledge useful or not?

Tags: vbscript, gis

Someone I know wants to progress in their job as an advanced GIS user, and asked me if Mapinfo's MapBasic is similar to VisualBasic.

I thought it was more like VBScript, having once been in the company of Mapinfo users.

Is it a good path to study VisualBasic (I have some old books lying around you see).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapBasic is similar to VB Script and Visual Basic, because all three are flavours of Basic.

But it isn't *very* similar. It's less advanced than VBScript or Visual Basic. It has even less support for object-orientation.

The best way to learn MapBasic is to learn MapBasic itself. I think the Visual Basic books would just be a distraction.

Comment: thx! BTW, is there an online learning resource you would recommend (nb - it is for someone with zero programming experience)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about learning resources for beginner programmers. Personally, I learnt MapBasic from the online documentation, but that was after a lot of experience programming other languages first.